# SQL server 2000 backup without server services being started

Tags: sql, database, service, sql-server-2000

Due to one of the array disk failure in HP-server, sql server 2000 is failing to start, giving error WMI provider error . However to avoid any risk i just want to take backup without being server started, by saving the primary data file MDF,Transactional file LDF, etc.
If there is any possibility then help me.

Answer (score 1):

Should just be able to copy these files and attach them to a new instance on a different server.  Make sure you reference the transaction when you attach to the new server.  There will be a place in the attach dialog to specify the location of both the mdf and ldf file.  Any transactions that were incomplete when the server went down will be rolled back, which is usually what you want.

Comment: Thank you @aaronLS ! I was in server room :-p  , I have located all the MDF and LDF file , can you provide some guidelines for safe procedure.

Comment: I really don't have any other recommendations if you don't have any other specific questions.  If you can successfully attach the DB and log, then you will be in good shape.  The only transactions that will be lost were those which were not completed when the server went down, which should be very few.  What those failed transactions, if any, mean differs from application to application.  It is something the app developers will have to assess.

Comment: Note the server is smart enough to look at the LDF and know what transactions were complete and which were not.  This is how it ensures the database is not corrupted, even if it went down suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use sp_attach_db to attach your MDF/LDF files. These are not backups but they are the next best thing if that's all you have. So copy the MDF and LDF files somewhere and then sort out the WMI issue.

A WMI failure is not that catastrophic. It is a layer that allows external processes to inspect and alter SQL Server (among other thins). If WMI failure is the worst thing that has happened then your database will not be affected.

Comment: Thanks @Electric ok i will run the SP on other alternate server hope cpying MDF and LDF files would get the most recent backup.

Comment: Good luck. Obviously you can find lots of doco on sp_attach_db online.